# Callback g_source_set_callback allways be called?

Tags: c++, c, glib

i am learning about gsocket and want to try to write a simple program to handle any packet i received, but function callback always be called when just only one packet came.This is my simple code:

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <gio/gio.h>
#include <libsoup/soup.h>
#include <glib-object.h>

gboolean has_packet(GIOChannel *source, GIOCondition condition, gpointer data){
    g_printf("has packet\n");

    return TRUE;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    g_type_init();

    GInetAddress *iface_address = g_inet_address_new_from_string ("0.0.0.0");
    GSocketAddress *bind_address = g_inet_socket_address_new (iface_address, 12345);
    GSocket *sock;
    GError *err = NULL;
    sock = g_socket_new(G_SOCKET_FAMILY_IPV4,
                    G_SOCKET_TYPE_DATAGRAM,
                    G_SOCKET_PROTOCOL_UDP,
                    &err);
    g_assert(err == NULL);

    g_socket_bind(sock, bind_address, TRUE, &err);
    g_assert(err == NULL);

    //int fd = g_socket_get_fd(sock);
    //GIOChannel* channel = g_io_channel_unix_new(fd);
    //guint source = g_io_add_watch(channel, G_IO_IN,
    //                        (GIOFunc) test, NULL);
    //g_io_channel_unref(channel);
    GSource *source = g_socket_create_source (sock, G_IO_IN,
                                                      NULL);
    g_source_set_callback (source, (GSourceFunc)has_packet, NULL, NULL);

    GMainLoop *loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);
    g_source_attach(source ,g_main_loop_get_context(loop));

    g_main_loop_run(loop);
    g_main_loop_unref(loop);
}
```

i hope when has one packet come, just one link "has packet" will be print, but it run forever. Could you help me work out where I am going wrong please.

UPDATE: i need to read data in socket.

```
gboolean has_packet(GIOChannel *source, GIOCondition condition, gpointer data)
{
    GSocket *sock = (GSocket *)data;
    char buf[65536];
    GSocketAddress *address = NULL;
    gssize bytes;
    GInputVector vector;
    GSocketControlMessage **messages;
    gint num_messages;

    GError *error = NULL;

    vector.buffer = buf;
    vector.size = 65536;
    bytes = g_socket_receive_message (sock,
                                      &address,
                                      &vector,
                                      1,
                                      &messages,
                                      &num_messages,
                                      NULL,
                                      NULL,
                                      &error);
    g_printf("has packet\n");
    g_printf("bytes = %zd\n", bytes);
    g_printf("num_message = %d\n", num_messages);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should `return FALSE` (or `return G_SOURCE_REMOVE`) from the callback if you only want it to be called once.

In addition, you start the main loop with `g_main_loop_run()` and that will run forever until `g_main_loop_quit()` is called. So you should quit the main loop at some point (presumably you want it to quit after a packet is received, so you should call `g_main_loop_quit()` in `has_packet()`.

Comment: thanks for answer, but i want receive more packet, not just one, and i want program run forever to hanlde any packet.